# How to get list in mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm learning MVC and start with very basic delete, update modules. I use ADO.Net Entity Framework Database Approach.

1. I create database
2. I create MVC BASIC project
3. In Model add ADO.NET Entity Framework
4. Add Home Controller and make view

In Home Controller I get list of Students

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CollegeManagementSystem.Models;

namespace CollegeManagementSystem.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            CMSEntities cx = new CMSEntities();
            var l = cx.Students.ToList();
            return View(l);
        }
     }
}
```

In `Index.cshtml` I get this list by including

```
@model List<CollegeManagementSystem.Models.Student>
```

And use `HTML Helpers` to show the information

```
@foreach (var x in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@x.studentname</td>
        <td>@x.studentage</td>
        <td><a href="/Home/Detail/@x.studentid">Detail</a></td>
        <td><a href="/Home/Update/@x.studentid">Update</a></td>
        <td><a href="/Home/Delete/@x.studentid">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Now, I want to use LINQ to SQL classes without Model.

I add Linq to SQL classes by click on project and add `LINQ TO SQL`

Here I need two things

1. How I get list of students with `LINQ` syntax?
2. How I get this information in `View` to show?

Please help!

Comment: What do you mean _without a model_?

Comment: In Model I cannot make any class or didn't add any ORM. I just add LINQ TO SQL Class in project and try to get list of student in controller and show in view.

Comment: without model ? Model is heart of mvc. Without model we cannot call it as MVC

Comment: because I am new in MVC, can you tell me then how I achieve this. I nee this with LINQ to SQL instead of Entity framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Code

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CMSEntities cx = new CMSEntities();
        Viewbag.student = cx.Students.ToList();
        return View();
    }
```

**View**

Removed  below the  code

```
 @model List<CollegeManagementSystem.Models.Student> is removed
```

change below the code

```
@foreach (var x in Viewbag.student as List<CollegeManagementSystem.Models.Student> )
{
   <tr>
     <td>@x.studentname</td>
     <td>@x.studentage</td>
     <td><a href="/Home/Detail/@x.studentid">Detail</a></td>
     <td><a href="/Home/Update/@x.studentid">Update</a></td>
     <td><a href="/Home/Delete/@x.studentid">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it **without EF** like this:

**1- Create Model Class for Student**

**2- Create StudentDBHandle.cs class for handling all the database operations**

**3- Use StudentDBHandle.cs in Action**

**4- Use Model Class for Student in View**

See **[this article](http://www.completecsharptutorial.com/mvc-articles/insert-update-delete-in-asp-net-mvc-5-without-entity-framework/)** for more information.

Answer (score 0):

**Hey Try this...**

> **Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CMSEntities cx = new CMSEntities();
        Viewbag.student = cx.Students.ToList();
        return View();
    }
```

> **View**

```
@foreach (var x in Viewbag.student as List<CollegeManagementSystem.Models.Student> )
{
   <tr>
     <td>@x.studentname</td>
     <td>@x.studentage</td>
     <td><a href="/Home/Detail/@x.studentid">Detail</a></td>
     <td><a href="/Home/Update/@x.studentid">Update</a></td>
     <td><a href="/Home/Delete/@x.studentid">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

@foreach (var item in Model)
                {

```
                         <td>
                       @Html.DisplayFor(m =>m.name
                    </td>
```

}